# How should I manage sessions in Hapijs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, session-cookies, hapi.js

I have to maintain the session for my frontend API.What are all the possible ways for session management in hapijs frontend API?

Answer (score 1):

The official plugin [hapi-auth-cookie](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie) is pretty popular and provides simple cookie-based session management.

If you like [json web tokens](http://jwt.io), [hapi-auth-jwt2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-auth-jwt2) is another popular and one that I am using in personal projects. It also includes an option to use cookies.

Also have a look at the [hapi tutorial on cookies](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/cookies?lang=en_US).

Edit: If you're worried about cookies/local storage being disabled you can try adding session information to the url of every request that the frontend makes. But this is more of a custom solution and I don't know any hapi modules that will manage this for you.

My advice is to see how many of your users *actually* disable cookies. It may not even be an issue for you.

Comment: Hi Cuthbert..thanks, yes
 I have used hapi-auth-cookie generally cookies be saved by the browser in its space in the client computer. Whenever the browser sends a request to that server it sends the cookie along with it. Then the server can identify the client using the cookie.
Disadvantage is that the users can opt to disable cookies using their browser preferences. In such case, the browser will not save the cookie at client computer and session tracking fails..
Is there any core modules.
I wish to maintain the session in server level not as locally in the browser

Comment: @Ramyachinna I don't know of any core modules that will manage sessions like you want. You might be able to store a JWT in local storage but that might also be disabled when cookies are disabled. Your other option might be to add session information to the url of every request that the frontend makes. But that's more of a custom solution.